# Query all the tables to get the max insert date on each table in a schema

Tags: date, insert, max, schema

I got a requirement to query all the tables in a schema to get the max insert date of individual table and I need to circulate this as a report to other team.

Please suggest the approach to write this query.

Comment: Do the date fields have different names?

Comment: The column name is same <INSERT_DT> across all the tables

Comment: 1. Query the schema for all of the table names.

Comment: 2. Use a loop to write SELECT statements like: `'SELECT MAX(insert_dt) FROM %s' % table_name`